# Can read files while executing from Netbeans, but not when executing JAR-file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have a program that needs to get information from a `XML-file`, and it's working as planned when I'am executing in NetBeans. When I'm on the other hand using the JAR-file and trying to do the same, I'm catching an `IOException`. Why is that? I'm using a String with the absolute path:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(strPath);
doc = db.parse(in);


java.io.FileNotFoundException: kmk (Det går inte att hitta filen)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at xmlDom.XMLTolk.skapaTolk(XMLTolk.java:82)
    at xmlDom.XMLTolk.<init>(XMLTolk.java:61)
    at xmlDom.Kloak.<init>(Kloak.java:46)
    at xmlDom.Kloak.main(Kloak.java:123)
```

This small program can parse the XML-file, but when I create a JAR-file of it - it doesn't work.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLTest {

        Document d;

        public XMLTest() throws ParserConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException {

            String docString = "C:\\someXML.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            dbf.setValidating(true);
            dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(docString);

            d = db.parse(in);
        }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException {

        XMLTest t = new XMLTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: may b facing file path issue, i knw it will throw file not found but u can look this

Comment: Please post that absolute path, and the stack trace for your exception.

Comment: Seems to be like it was a FileNotFoundException. The absolute path is C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\myXml.xml

Comment: Try to address the file in an absolute path. Also do what chrylis said. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to make your question as clear as possible so the experts here have it easy to spot the trouble and help you quickly. Keep in mind that every minute you spend crafting a good question is 5 minutes less of every reader trying to help you.

Comment: Also, if your error messages contain non-english reasons, please translate them for us.

Comment: Being a Scandinavian I can read the exception message and understand your method names.  Most other readers cannot!  This is actually a very good example of why you should keep your source in pure English instead of mixing English and your native language - because it will make it easier  to ask questions in an international forum like StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, thank you. "Det går inte att hitta filen" = Can't find file.

Comment: When I tested to get the information from a text-file, my error handler could notice a violation of a well-formedness constraint.

Comment: Yes, I will do that in the future, Thorbjörn.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to open a file named `kmk`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you're trying to read a file inside the application's classpath, and there's no filesystem file for the item when it's packaged in a jar. Use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream` instead.

Comment: He explicitly said he was using an absolute path, so that would not be the problem

Comment: @RobinJonsson Without a lot more detail than this, the most likely issue is that either he isn't actually using an absolute path or that the path is to a file in a development directory not available on the the deployment machine. I'll update if we get more information.

Answer (score 0):

When running with "java -jar foo.jar" the current working directory is not changed.

So when you are using relative paths they are found relative to your current working directory as set already, and not relative to the jar file location which is what you intuitively could have been expecting.

For most cases you can ask the JVM where it found the bytes used to define a given class and use that to derive the location of your jar file, which you can then use to locate the kmk file.